# Anthracycline vs Angucycline

Tags: drugs

Anthracyclines and angucyclines both have a tetracyclic core. Now, I need to classify urdamycinone B, fridamycin A, fridamycin G, and dehydroxyaquayamycin as anthracycline or angucycline. Both urdamycinone B and dehydroxyaquayamycin contain benz[a]anthraquinone core. While fridamycin A and G both contain anthraquinone core. I have classified urdamycinone B and dehydroxyaquayamycin as anthracyclines. And fridamycin A and G as angucyclines.

Did I classify the compounds correctly? And what are the differences between anthracyclines and angucyclines in terms of their sources and structures?

Comment: Have you tried drawing the structures? As far as I can tell, for example, the fridamycins *don't* have tetracyclic cores.

Comment: Yes. Urdamycinone B and dehydroxyaquayamycin have a tetracyclic benz[a]anthraquinone core while fridamycins A and G have a tricyclic anthraquinone core.